# Создание потокового видео x264 на C++

Tags: c++, видео, streaming

На данный момент система трансляций с камеры и экрана на удалённый сервер передаёт jpeg кадры, то есть используется покадровое сжатие. Для экономии трафика нужно перевести систему на трансляции с межкадровым сжатием с кодеком x264.
Что есть:
1. класс для захвата изображений с камеры или экрана с возможностью получать кадры jpeg или rgb/bgr;
2. класс для сетевого взаимодействия TCP/UDP;
3. статическая libx264.a (MinGW-w64).

Что надо:
1. Понимание того, как пользоваться libx264 и что нужно кодеку x264 на вход для создания видео ряда (кадры поступают в `unsigned char* buffer`, и все операции нужны в памяти - никаких файлов); Будет ли кодек работать с RGB/BGR или обязательно конвертировать в YUV-форматы? Как управлять уровнем компрессии?
2. Понимание принципа потоковой передачи видео на низком уровне в разрезе c++. Как строятся пакеты - из кадров, кусков кадров, набора кадров?

Чего не хотелось бы: отсылов к ffmpeg.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

UPDATE
С пунктом 1 разобрался, оказалось в libx264 всё проще и логичнее, чем в libvpx, с которым я три месяца бился.

Прошу помощи по пункту 2.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "пакетами"? На разных уровнях обработки под этим могут подразумеваться очень разные вещи.

Comment: @VTT, я не знаю, по этому спрашиваю. Моя система сейчас "стримит"  через tcp по 20-25 jpeg кадров в секунду, в разрешении 640х480, занимая до 6 мбит/с трафика на одного пользователя, а их может быть до 30!  А на ютубе как-то идут прямые трансляции потоком в full hd и 4К, без подтормаживаний и с отличным качеством. Я хочу так же, но не поимаю как устроена технология такой передачи. Возможно мой вопрос про "пакеты" не совсем корректен, но... не знаю как ещё это сформулировать, так как, опять же, не понимаю технологию.